# Neo4jclient - Any example in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to access a Neo4j database from a VB.NET application. I found many examples for C#, but none for VB. Is there anybody out there who could provide a sample in VB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use a converter on the samples, or bridge the short gap and learn a bit of C#

Comment: Converting doesn't work, the code for Neo4jclient is very specific. I have tried a couple of converters, they all fail.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a vb.net function to query the Neo4j-database is:

```
Public Function GetIDByLblPropSoort(ByVal verzameling As String, ByVal label As String, ByVal prop As String, ByVal soort As String) As Object
Dim clnt As New GraphClient(GraphCon, User, Password)
clnt.ConnectAsync.Wait()

'fake-query
Dim query = clnt.Cypher.Return(Of String)("0").ResultsAsync

Select Case verzameling
    Case "<ALLES>"

        If soort = "<alles>" Then
            query = clnt.Cypher.Match("(c:" + label + ")") _
            .Return(Of String)("c.ID") _
            .OrderBy("c.achternaam + ' ' + c.voornaam") _
            .ResultsAsync
        ElseIf soort = "<geen soort>" Then
            query = clnt.Cypher.Match("(c:" + label + ")") _
            .Where("( NOT EXISTS ((:soort)-[:soort]->(c)) )") _
            .Return(Of String)("c.ID") _
            .OrderBy("c.achternaam + ' ' + c.voornaam") _
            .ResultsAsync
        Else
            query = clnt.Cypher.Match("(d:soort)-[:soort]->(c:" + label + ")") _
            .Where("(d.naam='" + soort + "' AND d.context='" + label + "' ) ") _
            .Return(Of String)("c.ID") _
            .OrderBy("c." + prop) _
            .ResultsAsync
        End If

    Case Else
        If soort = "<alles>" Then
            query = clnt.Cypher.Match("(e:verzameling)-[*1..2]->(c:" + label + ")") _
            .Where("( e.naam = '" + verzameling + "')") _
            .Return(Of String)("c.ID") _
            .OrderBy("c.achternaam + ', ' + c.voornaam") _
            .ResultsAsync
        ElseIf soort = "<geen soort>" Then
            query = clnt.Cypher.Match("(e:verzameling)-[*1..2]->(c:" + label + ")") _
            .Where("(e.naam = '" + verzameling + "' AND NOT EXISTS ((:soort)-[:soort]->(c)) )") _
            .Return(Of String)("c.ID") _
            .OrderBy("c.achternaam + ', ' + c.voornaam") _
            .ResultsAsync
        Else
            If label = "media" Then
                query = clnt.Cypher.Match("(d:soort)-[:soort]->(c:" + label + "), (e:verzameling)-[*1..2]->(c)") _
                .Where("(d.naam='" + soort + "' AND d.context='" + label + "' AND e.naam = '" + verzameling + "') ") _
                .Return(Of String)("c.ID") _
                .OrderBy("c." + prop) _
                .ResultsAsync
            Else
                query = clnt.Cypher.Match("(e:verzameling)-[:verzameling]->(d:soort), (d:soort)-[:soort]->(c:" + label + ")") _
                .Where("(d.naam='" + soort + "' AND d.context='" + label + "' AND e.naam = '" + verzameling + "') ") _
                .Return(Of String)("c.ID") _
                .OrderBy("c." + prop) _
                .ResultsAsync
            End If
        End If

End Select

query.Wait()
Return query.Result

End Function
```

You can call this sort of function from a sub using this code:

```
    Dim antwoord1, antwoord2 As Object
    Dim cypherreeks As String = ""
    Dim aantal As Integer

    antwoord1 = procs.GetIDByLblPropSoort(FilterVrzKeuze, label, "naam", type)

            Try
                aantal = antwoord1.count
                cypherreeks = antwoord1(0).ToString
            Catch ex As Exception
                Exit Sub
            End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Telerik Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) I used worked fine, taking the C# of:

```
var gc = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "neo4j", "neo");
gc.Connect();   
var results = gc.Cypher.Match("(n)").Return ((n) => n.Count()).Results;
```

Becomes:

```
Dim gc = New GraphClient(New Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "neo4j", "neo")
gc.Connect()
Dim results = gc.Cypher.Match("(n)").[Return](Function(n) n.[Count]()).Results
```

Which works absolutely fine.